# Does javascript user interaction stop search engine crawls?

Tags: javascript, search-engine, captcha, robots.txt, google-crawlers

I want to stop search engines and scrapers from visiting a certain set of URLs `www.example.com/no_crawl/XXX` that encode rarely-visited but highly CPU-intensive pages.

The technique should not rely on advisory notifications (robots.txt, no-follow tags) because it's easy for a bad-actor to blow past such notifications, and I can't take that chance.

I'm wondering if requiring a bit of user interaction might be enough to stop search engines. But I don't know how paranoid to be, and welcome your thoughts.

At the most basic level there is:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('Click OK to prove you are human.');window.location='http://www.example.com/no_crawl/X1';">
    Show the page
</a>
```

Or would today's crawlers that execute javascript understand that `alert` does nothing and so pass to the location-setting step, understand what it's doing, and visit the page I don't want them to?

Before you say that scrapers could still see the URL, I'm thinking it would be best to implement something like this:

```
<script>
function was_clicked() {
    a = 'http://www.exam';
    b = 'ple.com/no_crawl/X1';
    alert( 'Click OK to prove you are human.' );
    window.location = a+b;
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:was_clicked();">Show the page</a>
```

Or should I get even more complicated?  I really don't want to use a CAPTCHA, because it will dissuade users.

Thanks.

EDITS:

- Detecting the user agent doesn't work, because bad actors can spoof it, and because there are too many agent-types to be tracked for either white-listing or black-listing.
- The cookie idea is interesting, e.g. teaming it with a mouse-over event on the link to be clicked.  The URL would still need to scrambled, however, to frustrate scrapers, so I remain interested in how much javascript is needed to do that.
- The pages are not yet available on the web.  Good thought.

Comment: why dont you just detect the user-agent and block your server-side script from executing?

Comment: Is this the first page your users will come through? If not, it may be possible to store some cookies or localStorage data to prove they had some human interaction ( like a scroll that a robot will probably not trigger )

Comment: I agree with @YouQi you're not going to be able to deter any bad players if they really want to crawl, but you can scope their user-agent and make certain assumptions.. but an alert will not actually stop a crawler, they will usually not be allowing execution of js anyway

Comment: Bear in mind that if these pages are already public and accessible, it may be too late - the URLs may already be in indexes and visited as a starting point regardless of what does/doesn't link to them.

Comment: I think you need to address the infrastructure itself as this indicate a design/architecture problem. Why are the pages CPU-intensive? can some of the work be moved to client and be processed there? If not, consider a job-based setup transferring the job to a dedicated machine which does not affect web server etc. There is no absolute way of securing yourselves against crawlers. The only safe way is to take the pages down, or put the load somewhere else.. my 2 cents

Comment: @Ken Fyrstenberg: The load has to go somewhere, and the CPU cycles have to be paid for, so moving the load around doesn't help.  Would that the tasks could be made less CPU intensive.

Comment: None of these strategies are going to help you if someone links to one of the pages from another site. Best approach IMHO is to use robots.txt for polite crawlers, IP blocking for known bad crawlers, and accept the fact that you won't get all of them.